# Spring 3 Field Formatting

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, formatting, date-formatting

I am looking at using the Spring's Field formatting in particular the existing DateFormatter.  I do understand that I need to specify a pattern on an annotation in my POJO.

Instead of hard coding the pattern I need to be able to provide it dynamically, I know this is not feasible with annotations.  To properly support internationalization I would need to look up a pattern from a properties file before passing it to a Formatter.

Can anyone suggest an approach I can take?

Comment: Providing some kind of factory annotated with @component which will format you date according to your locale.

Comment: Found [this](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.0.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/ch05s06.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure however you may try implementing InitializingBean or init-method and set the values dynamically.

like suggested in [spring forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?31736-Setting-dynamic-Property) for cron expression.